# How do you read the definition of this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set as described here. If I is a set and $\{X_i\}_{i ∈ I}$ a family of sets indexed by I, we define the following:

$\Large\text{Definition}:\cap_{i\in I}X_i:=\{x|x\in X_i \quad\text{for all}\quad i\in I\}$

Now, the way I see it, is that I has many subsets $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$. Then the above definition says that the intersection of all these sets are the elements $x$.

I am not sure about this though. Why isn't $i$ given from 0 to n in the definition and why do we have only $x$? Is $x$ here a set or individual elements in the sets?

Comment: Do you know what is the meaning of $A \cap B$ if $A$ and $B$ are two arbitrary sets?

Comment: The set defined is the *intersection* of **all** the sets $X_i$, i.e. the set of those objects $x$ such that $x \in X_i$, for all $i \in I$.

Comment: $i$ is not given from $0$ to $n$ because we may have an infinite family of subsets (even an uncountable family). $x$ denotes individual elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$i$ does not go from $0$ to $n$ because $i$ is an element of the set $I$, which does not need to contain $0,1,\dots$.

In fact, the set $I$ can be not only **infinite**, but also **much larger** than just the natural numbers.

Examples:

- $I=\{1,2,3\}$. In this case, you have $X_1,X_2,X_3$, and the intersection $$\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$$
  is equal to $X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3$.
- $I=\mathbb N$. In this case, you have **infinitely many** sets $X_i$, and $$\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$$ denotes the intersection of **all** of them. So, for example, if $X_i=[0,\frac{1}{i}]$, then $$\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i = \{0\}$$
- $I=\mathbb R$. Yes, $I$ can be that big. There is no rule that says it can't. You can have, for example, $X_i=[-1, \sin(i)]$ which is a set that is defined for **every real $i$**. The intersection, in this case, would be $\{-1\}$.

---

I also see that you are confused about why there is only $x$, and nothing else, written in the definition. To make it more clear, try reading the definition out loud. The expression:

$$A=\{x| x\in X_i \text{ for all }i\in I\}$$

actually means

> "$A$ is the set of all such $x$ for which $x$ is an element of $X_i$ for all $i\in I$.

This, implicitly, also demands that yes, $x$ are indeed individual elements of the set.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks